# windows-ubuntu-bash + hypervisor winrm + ansible - Server not found in Kerberos database

Tags: kerberos, ansible, windows-server-2016, winrm, linux-subsystem

I'm struggling like a week with that issue, read every internet post about that problem.

## What we have

- Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with Hyper-V Role installed (netbios: hv)
- Virtual Machines (netbios: web, fs, dc) on Windows Server 2016 DataCenter
- Windows 10 Professional Laptop with Linux Subsystem installed (netbios: asuslin)
- Domain on dc.goodpeople.local and all the servers and clients (including hv) are joined Active Directory Domain
- AD CA installed with Intermediate Issuing CA on domain controller
- All servers got certificate with auto-enrollment policy to auth kerberos

I would like to configure all servers (including hv) with ansible from my windows 10 laptop with kerberos. For now, I just need a success win_ping to all of them.

## Configuration

- winrm configured on all the servers: hv, web, fs, dc and clinet: asuslin the same way: kerberos auth is turned on, https listener with valid certificate, firewall ports 5986 is opened
- as all windows 2016/win10 - powershell is the latest with .NET at least 4.5
- ansible on client was installed on linux subsystem according the documentation with all the necessary libs and valid certificate for asuslin client is used

## Actual Error

```
ansible hv -m win_ping -vvvv
ansible 2.5.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/alexsuslin/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.pyc
META: ran handlers
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_ping.ps1
<hv.goodpeople.local> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: alexsuslin@GOODPEOPLE.LOCAL on PORT 5986 TO hv.goodpeople.local
checking if winrm_host hv.goodpeople.local is an IPv6 address
calling kinit with subprocess for principal alexsuslin@GOODPEOPLE.LOCAL
hv.goodpeople.local | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "kerberos: authGSSClientStep() failed: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

## What is working

- I successfully can win_ping all the servers fs,dc,web and client asuslin
- I can `Enter-PSSession hv.goodpeople.local -UseSSL -Authentication Kerberos`
- As I can win_ping others servers, I assume my krb5.conf is configured correctly as well as ansible inventory file. E.g. if I run win_ping withing the group, all except hv.goodpeople.local is ok

## What I have already checked

- winrm from powershell to hv.goodpeople.local with kerberos and SSL --- OK
- SPN for hv.goodpeople.local compared to other servers: dc, web, fs --- ALMOST THE SAME (actually as hv is hyper-v role, there are some additional ones)
- my account credentials, tried with Domain Admin
- winrm SDDL on hv.goodpeople.local --- SEEMS OK
- SPNs of hv.goodpeople.local and delegation --- OK
- different types of ciphers of SSL cert between linux subsystem and hv.goodpeople.local --- OK
- kinit --- OK, ticket for 24h always valid
- `kvno HTTP/hv.goodpeople.local@GOODPEOPLE.LOCAL`  --> `HTTP/hv.goodpeople.local@GOODPEOPLE.LOCAL: kvno = 17`
- every page on google about that issue (including [serverfault.com])

  - dns is resolving for every machine, including hv
  - krb5.conf realm configured correctly with UPPERCASE and FQDN as well as ansible inventory

What brothers me the most is why the same config is not working on a single server while it is working on others? I have applied the configuration with powershell to be sure everything is the same. If someone can point what should I check more?

Comment: If you look at the various hosts do you see any differences if you do a `gci WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\` or `gci WSMan:\localhost\Service\`?

Comment: Chekcing HV vs asuslin, dc and web: 

1) Auth: Kerberos is enabled on all of them
2) CbtHardeningLevel is Relaxed (however I have tried Strict several days ago as far as I remeber)
3) RootSDDL string a bit different however: ```O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;DA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;...``` vs ```O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GX...```

Comment: Checking further SDDL and translating with ConvertFrom-SDDLString into readable format I found out that my hv server contains just a single additional permision for GOODPEOPLE\Domain Admins: AccessAllowed (GenericAll)} - and that is what I have added manually while trying to understand why I cannot connect to this server from bash and can do from the same  machine powershell

Comment: I have updoated RootSDDL to be the same as on web and other servers... nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was such a silly thing I made

On Windows (host) machine there was an entry in C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file

`192.168.88.20 srv-gp`

and that is my hv server... I have removed that and everything is working fine...

P.S. I found https://github.com/bgamble/pykerberos/blob/master/test.py script to test my kerberos authentication and from errors of

`sudo ./test.py -s HTTPS@hv.goodpeople.local -r GOODPEOPLE.LOCAL -p 5986 gssapi`

I found out strange connection to gp-srv... Immediately check /etc/host and windows hosts file and found the issue.

Comment: Wow, glad you found that.  That sounds tricky to troubleshoot

Comment: yep, spent so many hours with such a silly thing... funny enough when I tested dns everything worked fine.